# How to click an element using selenium webdriver present under role=alertdialog?

Tags: selenium, exception, button, webdriver, click

When I open a url, there is a cookie banner which opens up, which is not an alert, html is something like

```
<div role="alertdialog>
<div class="classname">
<button id="buttonID">
```

I am trying to click on this button by writing the xpath

```
//div[@role='alertdialog']//div[@class='classname']//button[@id='buttonID']
```

Which returns the element on searching.

While running the automated script however I get nosuchelement exception

Any help on handling and clicking inside similar banner would be helpful

I tried nesting the div and every time element is returned on searching but not clicked while script runs.
noSuchElement or noSuchAlert is thrown

I have tried .click(), javascriptexecuter and driver.switchTo().alert(); as well, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may arise when the correct XPath is not defined or the popout element did not in the DOM.

1st issue: You can get the XPath element correctly by Google Chrome Extension SelectorsHub.

2nd issue: You have to switch the frame that which that popout renders.
[Check this example](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/)